# RStudio ->RMarkdown/knitr -> html -> blog doesn't work for me

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, rstudio

I have been trying to use RStudio and knitr to create blog posts. I have followed the method previously described for tumblr by Jeff Horner here ([Part I](http://jeffreyhorner.tumblr.com/post/25804518110/blog-with-r-markdown-and-tumblr-part-i)) and here ([Part II](http://jeffreyhorner.tumblr.com/post/25943954723/blog-with-r-markdown-and-tumblr-part-ii)).

Briefly that is a custom CSS for tumblr, make sure html editor is enabled and then create a .md and html file using **knitr** and **markdown** packages.

```
library(knitr)
knit('tut5.Rmd')
library(markdown)
markdownToHTML("tut5.md", "tut5.html", fragment.only = TRUE)
```

This is a sample of my html:

```
<p><FONT style="font-size:15px"></p>
<h2>Model Formulae and Linear Models</h2>
<p>In many ways the R language is similar to other programming languages (Matlab, Python, Scala) but it has a few unique features due to its focus on statistics. Amongst these model formulae are a useful shorthand for representing the relations between data variables - in particular to specify linear models (e.g. regression and multiple regression)- and they appear in both statistical and plotting expressions.</p>
```

Sadly I find this html file just creates a blank post when I load it into **tumblr** or **wordpress** blogs. I think I tried **blogger** too a while ago but I cant remember if I used the same steps.

I am using the latest RStudio and package versions as of today.

So...

1. Has anyone else been able to manage this successfully to these (or similar) sites.
2. If so do they have a different method?
3. Or am I doing something wrong?

I know about RPubs - it's great but I just find the style and particularly page width poor  for teaching/reading.

Many Thanks

Comment: it would help a lot if you can point to the real website; sounds like you screwed up the tumblr theme or something.